# Are lambdas cached at compile-time in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, lambda

Allocating a lambda is expensive. On MSVC it allocates ~128 bytes last time I checked. This makes creating lambdas in a loop a serious performance issue.

In Python, all literals are treated kind of like `constexpr`, they are calculated (if needed, like `x = 10 * 25`) and then cached at compile-time and simply substituted where needed.

I am wondering if this is done in C++ since something like this...

```
for (auto thing: things)
    [](auto x){ /* do stuff */ }(thing);
```

...looks both like it would allocate the lambda a bunch of times and like it could use the automatic caching I described above.

So, is this a performance issue in C++? Would it be better to store the lambda in a variable before the for-loop and use that variable or is it fine as it is?

Comment: This is likely to be extremely implementation-specific. However, note that a lambda with no capture is required to be convertible to a function pointer. Under the hood, it is just a normal function. Likely that is what will happen here. You'll have to check for yourself though.

Comment: depending on context lambda in C++ behaves like anonymous function or like functional object. In your strange example it is just anonymous function, so with "AS IF rule" compiler has right  to optimize this and drop lambda (body of lambda will become part of `for` loop).

Comment: Compilers are generally pretty smart when it comes to local variable allocations, even for dynamic stuff like creating (but not storing) an object. It's very likely that objects created inside a loop will have their memory allocated when the function enters, or in the first iteration of the loop. Then that memory will be reused for every object "created" inside the loop. You can check the generated assembly code to make sure of this behavior.

Comment: Unrelated: a `lambda` in python is very much a dynamic object and will allocate memory every time. (it needs to capture its environment)

Comment: First off: that lambda does not capture `thing`, and obviously if you do capture 128 bytes then the lambda will take 128+ bytes. In addition to what @Someprogrammerdude notes, compilers which can use profiling data can do even better. They can check if actual flow patterns, and see if the lambda allocation is needed in every function call (so just make the stack frame larger) or only occasionally (do the equivalent of an `alloca`. ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your lambda is noncapturing and invoked immediately, any compiler worth its salt will hoist the lambda to a static function and inline the call with zero overhead.

Are you sure you're not confusing lambdas with `std::function`?